# Output a part of a String if the beginning of the String starts with a keyword

Tags: java, substring, filereader, keyword

So, i started learning Java and its superfun and confusing at the same time.

I use filereader to read the content of a file with no problem, and also output it in another file and output a substring on a given place in the String. *(Yes, for those that know EDI you know its a VDA file)*

However, i want to read the beginning of a line and then output several substrings based on the position in the row..

**Desired output:
Find 55901, then Stringname = substringname(5, 12) Stringname = substringname(13, 20) Etc.**

This is what im reading in to the inputString, every line is 128 chars long ̶b̶̶u̶̶t̶̶ ̶̶i̶̶t̶̶ ̶̶h̶̶a̶̶s̶̶ ̶̶b̶̶e̶̶e̶̶n̶̶ ̶̶t̶̶r̶̶i̶̶m̶̶e̶̶d̶̶ ̶̶i̶̶n̶̶ ̶̶t̶̶h̶̶e̶̶ ̶̶p̶̶o̶̶s̶̶t̶̶ ̶̶a̶̶u̶̶t̶̶o̶̶m̶̶a̶̶t̶̶i̶̶c̶̶a̶̶l̶̶l̶̶y̶:

```
55101BUYX     SELLLX    0022200223210924                                                                                        
55201XQ 000897350210924  PARTNUMERXXX                            ZZ           S000000V            0000000000                  
55301000000000000000000000000000000000000000000I                                                                               
554012109240000000000462 2109270000000000000 2109280000000000000 2109290000000000000 2109300000000000000 2110010000000000000   
554012110040000000000000 2110050000000000000 2110060000000000000 2110070000000000000 0000000000000000000 0000000000000000000   
55701                                                                                                    JP010 ASDFGHJK         
55901_output000000200000020000004000000000000020000001
```

This is what i have so far:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        File file = new File("C:\\Users\\Mail\\Desktop\\VDA Reader\\VDA.txt");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);
        String input = "";
        String buyer = "";
        //Scan next line if exists
        try {
            while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
                input = input.concat(scan.nextLine() + "\n");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println("Error in the code");
        }
        scan.close();
        buyer = input.substring(5, 13);
        System.out.println("Buyer "+buyer);

    }
}
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. Do you want to split your lines somehow? Are you looking for specific substrings in the whole file? What does the code that you already have do? What should it do instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. I think you should do that before concatenating the next line from scanner to the input.

```
try {
        while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
            String nextLine = scan.nextLine();
            //now find 55901
            String keyword = "55901"
            if(nextLine.startsWith(keyword){
                //go ahead and extract the content you want from nextLine
                buyer = nextLine.substring(5, 13);
            }
            input = input.concat(nextLine + "\n");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much, that worked like a charm but i ran in to anotheer problem that i cant seem to find the answer to. I extract 12 substrings with this method but the last 2 strings is always empty. Also when i add an else if to find the next 55401 row it doesnt contain any values.

From the code below i get the following, the Strings 6 & 7 dosnt get vales.
Ship 210924 | QTY 000000462
Ship 210927 | QTY 000000000
Ship 210928 | QTY 000000000
Ship 210929 | QTY 000000000
Ship 210930 | QTY 000000000
Ship  | QTY
Ship  | QTY

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    File file = new File("C:\\Users\\Mail\\Desktop\\VDA Reader\\VDA.txt");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);
    String input = "";
    String shipDate1 = "";
    String qty1 = "";
    String shipDate2 = "";
    String qty2 = "";
    String shipDate3 = "";
    String qty3 = "";
    String shipDate4 = "";
    String qty4 = "";
    String shipDate5 = "";
    String qty5 = "";
    String shipDate6 = "";
    String qty6 = "";
    String shipDate7 = "";
    String qty7 = "";
    String callOffs = "55401";
    //Scan next line if exists
    try {
        while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
            String outPut = scan.nextLine();
            if(outPut.startsWith(callOffs)){
                shipDate1 =     outPut.substring(5, 11);
                qty1 =          outPut.substring(15, 24);
                shipDate2 =     outPut.substring(25, 31);
                qty2 =          outPut.substring(35, 44);
                shipDate3 =     outPut.substring(45, 51);
                qty3 =          outPut.substring(55, 64);
                shipDate4 =     outPut.substring(65, 71);
                qty4 =          outPut.substring(75, 84);
                shipDate5 =     outPut.substring(85, 91);
                qty5 =          outPut.substring(95, 104);
                shipDate6 =     outPut.substring(105, 101);
                qty6 =          outPut.substring(115, 124);
            }
            if (outPut.startsWith(callOffs + shipDate1)){
                shipDate7 =     outPut.substring(5, 11);
                qty7 =          outPut.substring(15, 24);

            }
            input = input.concat(outPut + "\n");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e){
    }
    scan.close();
    System.out.println("Ship "+shipDate1 + " | QTY " + qty1);
    System.out.println("Ship "+shipDate2 + " | QTY " + qty2);
    System.out.println("Ship "+shipDate3 + " | QTY " + qty3);
    System.out.println("Ship "+shipDate4 + " | QTY " + qty4);
    System.out.println("Ship "+shipDate5 + " | QTY " + qty5);
    System.out.println("Ship "+shipDate6 + " | QTY " + qty6);
    System.out.println("Ship "+shipDate7 + " | QTY " + qty7);
```